# Combine two tables into one table based on a common columne

Tags: sql-server

If I have table A with column name `time`, `value1` and also table B with column name `time`, `value2`. How can I join these two tables into one table with the columns `time`, `value1`, `value2` with sql server?

> Table A: time, value1
>
> Table B: time, value2

Output:

> time, value1, value2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a classic [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
SELECT t1.time, t1.value1, t2.value2 
FROM Table1 t1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.time=t2.time
```

PS! In some databases `LEFT JOIN` is called `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Went old school using the optional OUTER identifier for ANSI-92 compatibility. Throwback Thursdays are in full effect.

Comment: what if the times are different? i want to put nulls if there is no times are matching.

Comment: @Mat If there is no a matching- a time that is on `table1` but doesn't have a match on `table2` you will get the following result: `t1.time,t1.value,NULL`

Answer (score 0):

A funny approach would be like:-

```
SELECT time, value1, '' as value2
from A

UNION ALL

SELECT time, '' as value1, value2
FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.time, A.value1, A.value2 
FROM Table1 A  
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.time=B.time
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".